# Local maximum versus global maximum

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Let's say that a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ obtains a local maximum at the point $(x_0,y_0)$, and this is the only local maximum. Are we able to say that this point is a global maximum by virtue of the fact that it is the only maximum? Is it possible that the function may not have a global maximum?

I'm getting the sense that the answer is no when regarded as a function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, but if it's restricted to a closed interval, the answer is yes. I'm not certain, however.

Comment: First, think of a function with no maximum. Then perturb it a little to make a local maximum.

Comment: This fails for functions in general, but I'm pretty sure it's true for a function with compact support.

Comment: No to all your claims. For example, take a piecewise function on $[-1,0]$. On $[-1,-.1]$ make it some nice function, differentiable, concave and derivative vanishes. And on $[-.1,0)$ take $x\mapsto -1/x$ and put $0\mapsto 0$.

Comment: clearly we have to assume continuity or else it doesn't make much sense to talk about local behavior...

Comment: The function $x \mapsto (x-1)x(x+1)$ has a local $\max$ and $\min$ but no global $\max$ or $\min$.

Comment: In case there's only one extreme value, it's a global one.  Note that this isn't true for functions $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ the function $\varphi(x)= x^3-3x$ has the only local maximum at $x=-1$ and $\varphi(-1)=2.$ Clearly it is not a global maximum as the function is unbounded from above. Similar effect occurs for  any open interval. For example the function $f:(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\to \mathbb{R},$ $f(t)=\varphi(\tan t)$ admits the only local maximum at $t=-\pi/4.$

Concerning $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R},$ any continuous function admits a global maximum due to the Weierstrass theorem. But if we give up the continuity we can take $$\psi(x)=\begin{cases} x^3-3x & -2\le x<3\\
0 &\quad\quad\ \ x=3\end{cases}$$ The function has local maximum at $x=-1$ but there is no global maximum.